# Visual Studio 2022 complaining about .Net6.0 sdk

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I recently installed visual studio 2022 and I am getting below error when I am trying to run simple Hello World console application targeting .net6.0 framework. I even tried uninstalling and doing clean installation again but that did not help. does anyone has pointer of why this issue might be occurring? and how to resolve this?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3971 The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0.107" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK. ConsoleApp6 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1217
```

This is program.cs

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

This is csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0.107</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

However, I noticed when I check target framework dropdown, I do not see .Net core 6.0 as option. so this might be an issue. However, I am not sure why this would happen. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio 2022 but that did not help either.

[image: TargetFramework]

Comment: Can you please add contents of your .csproj file. Cause AFAIK there is no such thing as .NET**Framework**,Version=v6xxx

Comment: @GuruStron no. I am talking about .net 6.0 one of the latest .net core versions. I have just created console application in VS 2022. It created default hello world program. I will update the post with that snippet but that piece is pretty standard. I know my issue is due to some incorrect installation of visual studio 2022 but not sure what has messed up in the installation which is causing the build error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. I am posting as answer incase it helps someone.

I uninstalled every visual studio version I had installed in my machine and also uninstalled every .Net Core SDK if any from my machine. Restarted my machine and did reinstallation of Visual Studio 2022 and I ensured I select all the required .Net Core SDKs (by default .Net 6.0 will be selected but I required .Net 2.1 as well for one of my project)

Once I did above steps, issue was resolved